# ajax передача файла в php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Как передать файл из input type=file при помощи ajax или post методом POST файл в файл phpне могу толкового ничего найти и сделать.

Пытаюсь так но что то не выходит ничего хорошего из этого

```
$.ajax({
url: "ajax.php",
type: "post",
data: "upload_file="+$('#file')[0].files[0],
success: function(){
},
error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
}
dataType: "json"
});
```

Пытаюсь в php ловить так

```
$_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это позволяет делать FormData

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "post",
    data: new FormData($('#file').parents('form:first')[0]),

    /*при использовании FormData флаги processData и contentType надо ставить в false*/
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,

    success: function(){

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

    }
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Только советую исследовать на предмет совместимости сначала http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2

UPD:
Подправил код. При таком запросе в PHP дальше надо работать с `$_FILES['file']` - как и обычно.

Comment: А как его ловить в php таким способом?

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров Ловить также. Через $_FILES.

Comment: @Arnial, это понятно, под каким именем? Указанным в инпуте?

Comment: @Владимир Александров name у инпута, указать не забудь разумеется. Под таким именем в $_FILES и будет