# Javascript прочитать содержимое input file и выгрузить через XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, кодировка, base64, upload

Всем привет! Стоит задача: загрузить файл (.exe) на сервер, выбранный файл через

```
<input type="file" id="myfile">
```

Читаю так(Javascript):

```
var myfile='';
var input = document.getElementById('myfile');
input.onchange = function(evt){
    var tgt = evt.target || window.event.srcElement, files = tgt.files;
    if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = function(){
                myfile = fr.result;
            }
        fr.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        }
}
```

Теперь имею переменную "myfile" вида:

```
"data:application/msdownload;base64,0J/RgNC40LLQtdGCINC80LjRgCE= .... и т.д."
```

Т.е. в base64 данных и есть сырой файл...
При попытке загрузить файл на сервер, все хорошо, НО меняется кодировка...
Что делаю не так?

Загружаю так:

```
        var fd = new FormData();
        var b = new Blob([atob(decodeURIComponent((myfile).split(',')[1]))],{type: 'application/msdownload'});
        fd.append('file', b, "myfile.exe");
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "http://myserver/");
        xhr.send(fd);
```

Всё бы хорошо. Файл загружается норм. Но скачанный файл имеет другую кодировку... Т.е. он не открывается. Из-за этого и размер файла меняется.

Пробовал добавить заголовок разных кодировок при отправке, но безрезультатно.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "charset=windows-1251"); 
.............
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "charset=utf-8");
и др......
```

Что не так?

Прошу не предлагать загрузку файла напрямую...  т.к. файл необходимо сохранить локально на время ... а потом выгрузить.

**Дополнено(для уточнения вопроса):**

Имеем строку Base64 вида:

```
0J/RgNC40LLQtdGCINC80LjRgCE=
```

Знаем, что в ней сохранен контент исполняемого файла "SecretFile.exe". Полученный способом описанным выше.

При декодировании стандартным window.atob содержимое не равно источнику. Как получить исходник из сырого закодированного в Base64, FileReader`ом.

Comment: Этот вопрос - дубликат этого http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568543 . Учимся пользоваться поиском

Comment: Не совсем дубликат, см. внимательней.

Comment: @Other точно, спс

Comment: @Tommi лучше отредактируй вопрос - совсем непонятно, что тебе нужно добавить в `FormData` файл именно из текстовой переменной, предварительно взятой из input=file

Comment: А почему промежуточное представление именно data-URL и base64, а не тупо бинарный ArrayBuffer?

Comment: На деле помогает пропустить полученный файл через функцию `utf8_decode`. Почему - хотел бы услышать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы странно захватываете файл, предлагаю два более простых варианта:

1.FormData конструировать с формой данного файла

```
var fd = new FormData($('#myfile').parents('form:first')[0]);
//но название на стороне сервера будет как name у input-а #myfile
```

2.Добавляем файл в FormData

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', $('#myfile')[0].files[0], "myfile.exe");
```

Всё, можно отправлять в xhr. На стороне сервера работать так-же, как и с файлом отправленным обычным способом.

UPD:
Если стоит задача загрузить файл именно предварительно сохранённой из input=file строкой: попробуйте вместо `readAsDataURL` - [readAsText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText). Как говорит MDN - там можно подставить определённую кодировку. И уже с этим текстом создать Blob. Надеюсь поможет, но не уверен.

UPD2:
А ещё вот - практически [ответ на ваш вопрос на большом SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript) . Вам же именно Blob из base64 надо правильно создать.

Comment: Вы упускаете что в распоряжении может быть только строка `data:application/msdownload;base64,0J/RgNC40LLQtdGCINC80LjRgCE= .... и т.д.`.

Comment: @Other да, но в начале вопроса видно, что там читают эту строку с помощью `input.onchange`

Comment: "файл необходимо сохранить локально **на время**". Может в localStorage сохраняет, а после N перезагрузок браузера пытается слать.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр Действительно изначально строка base64 была считана с помощью input file. Но читайте полностью вопрос - просьба,  не предлагать загрузку файла напрямую.

Comment: @Other может, тогда дополню.

Comment: @Other Так точно! В localStorage

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр `попробуйте readAsText('myencoding')` Для этого мне надо знать изначальную кодировку. Я её не знаю. Но хотелось бы знать, как определить её и  реализовать этот метод.

Comment: @Tommi нет, поидее не начальную - а соответствующую кодировке страницы. Возможно попробовать однобайтную. Но я дополнил ответ ещё раз - думаю это точно поможет.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр `UPD2` СПАСИБО! Вроде то что надо! Завтра разберусь...и отмечу палец вверх ))

Answer (score 0):

*Перенесено из вопроса*

**РЕШЕНО:**

Попытки перекодирования из кодировки в кодировку ( как предлагал @Other UTF-8, 1251...и пр.) не дали никакого результата. Как и попытки чтения файла разными методами readAsText(), readAsBinaryString()... впрочем был важен момент с Base64 а именно readAsDataURL(), который содержит те-же данные, что и при чтении другими методами, в удобной форме для их хранения.

Решение, как часто бывает, простое. Спасибо @ГончаровАлександр за [ответ на мой вопрос на большом SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/5312848)

Как оказалось декодированная строка из Base64 не является напрямую "образом" файла, а символами для каждого байта двоичных данных, которые можно преобразовать с помощью функции ([источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/5312848)):

```
function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
contentType = contentType || '';
sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
var byteArrays = [];

for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
  byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
}

var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

byteArrays.push(byteArray);
}

var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
return blob;
}
```

Всем спасибо! Может кому и пригодиться.